# How to rewrite data to same json file by updating a specific value in swift

Tags: json, swift, xcode, xcuitest

I have a json file and decoded the json with swift. But now I need to update a value and write the updated value back to same json file.

```
Example json file:
```

```
         { 
       "Active_ProfileComplete":[ 
          { 
             "name":"StudioFEAutomation TestUser1",
             "weight":"200",
             "overrideWeight":"100",
             "status":"not processed"
          },
          { 
             "name":"StudioFEAutomation TestUser2",
             "weight":"200",
             "overrideWeight":"100",
             "status":"not processed"
          }
       ],
       "Active_ProfileComplete_monthlypass":[ 
          { 
             "name":"StudioFEAutomation TestUser31",
             "weight":"200",
             "overrideWeight":"100",
             "status":"not processed"
          }
       ]
    }
```

In the first test run let's say I processed 1st member now I want to update the status field to processed so when I read the file in the second run then the status field processed.

I tried decoding the json file and reading values. But I don't know how to update the same json file by changing value of key's in dictionary.

This is what I did for decoding,

```
 let decoder = JSONDecoder()
    let jsonResult = try decoder.decode(MembersInfo.self, from: data)
```

expected result - 
    Change the status key value after processing each member and write back to same json file

```
         { 
       "Active_ProfileComplete":[ 
          { 
             "name":"StudioFEAutomation TestUser1",
             "weight":"200",
             "overrideWeight":"100",
             "status":"processed"
          },
          { 
             "name":"StudioFEAutomation TestUser2",
             "weight":"200",
             "overrideWeight":"100",
             "status":"not processed"
          }
       ],
       "Active_ProfileComplete_monthlypass":[ 
          { 
             "name":"StudioFEAutomation TestUser31",
             "weight":"200",
             "overrideWeight":"100",
             "status":"not processed"
          }
       ]
    }
```

Comment: `var` declare the status property.

Comment: @Joa- I am new to swift. Can you please help me on this -If I want to update status for by "Active_ProfileComplete"  for name:  Test User 2 how do I do that.

Comment: Add you code for the structs you use for decoding, MembersInfo etc

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have created `Codable` classes for you json.

So, I have created following classes for above json.

```
struct MembersInfo : Codable {

    var activeProfileComplete : [ActiveProfileComplete]?
    var activeProfileCompleteMonthlypass : [ActiveProfileCompleteMonthlypas]?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case activeProfileComplete = "Active_ProfileComplete"
        case activeProfileCompleteMonthlypass = "Active_ProfileComplete_monthlypass"
    }
}

struct ActiveProfileCompleteMonthlypas : Codable {

    var name : String?
    var overrideWeight : String?
    var status : String?
    var weight : String?
}

struct ActiveProfileComplete : Codable {
    var name : String?
    var overrideWeight : String?
    var status : String?
    var weight : String?
}
```

where every value is variable.

After decoding json data, Now, for example I'm changing value of first element as follow.

```
// Decode original json
let decoder = JSONDecoder()
var jsonResult = try decoder.decode(MembersInfo.self, from: json!)

// Change status
jsonResult.activeProfileComplete![0].status = "processed"

// Encode new updated json to data
let encoder = JSONEncoder()
var encodeData = try encoder.encode(jsonResult)
```

So, now you have data and you can easily convert it to json by using `JSONSerialization`

I hope this is solution what you are looking for.

Comment: I can get encodedData and then how to save in same Json file?